# htacces -FallbackResource strange behaviour

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

When testing some programming I found that htaccess -fallbackresource demonstrated some strange behaviour in combination with my php code.

I have a htaccess file with the following code:

```
FallbackResource index.php
```

I also have a single php file with this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset ($_SESSION['times_visited'])){
    $_SESSION['times_visited']++;
}
else{
    $_SESSION['times_visited'] = 1;
}

?>
<html>
<head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='not_existing.css'>
        <script href='not_existing.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>You visited this page <?php echo $_SESSION['times_visited'];?> times</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Both the .css and .js files are not existing on the disk.

When I first run the php it outputs:

```
You visited this page 1 times
```

When i refresh the page i get:

```
You visited this page 3 times
```

After each page refresh, instead of going up by 1, the counter goes up by 2!

When I remove the script-tag, the counter still goes up by two.
When I remove the link-tag, the counter goes up by one.

When I add another five link-tags, the counter goes up by 5
When I add another five script-tags, the counter only goes up by one.

The original problem was in a much larger program, so it took me some time to figure out what was going on. 
Eventually, i found out that the non-existing file in the link-tag, activated the fallbackresource causing the index.php to run an extra time.

What I can't figure out is why the link-tag and script-tag behave different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script isn't loaded because there's no `href` attribute for `<script>`, you probably want `src`. That's why your `<script>` tags appear to do nothing. Getting that out of the way, there's an additional anomaly you're probably seeing.

The `<?php ?>` stuff is rendered on the server. That happens *before* the browser even gets the page's content, which is *before* the browser knows to even load what's in the `<link>` and the `<script>` tags.

So technically, you may be seeing the counts from the *previous* page load. Are you sure something like this isn't happening?

1. visits = 0
2. load index.php, session starts, visits = 1
3. browser renders page, sees visits = 1, loads 1 non-existing link, visits = 2
4. load index.php, visits = 3
5. browser renders page, sees visits = 3, loads 1 non-existing link, visits = 4

etc.

Comment: With src instead of href, the link tag and script tags behave the same. I could have looked at this for hours without finding the problem because i was focusing on the php and not on the html. so, thanks a lot! (Feel kind of stupid now for making such a rooky mistake...)